# PostScript Default CTM values

Tags: matrix, transformation, postscript

when I display the default CTM I get the following

```
[1.33333 0.0 0.0 1.33333 0.0 0.0]
```

What is the reason for the 1.33333? If I understood the CTM correctly, the first entry is `s_x*cos` and the fourth entry is `s_y*cos`? So why the scaling is 1.33333 per default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CTM is the means for mapping from user space to device space, so the initial CTM will map the default user space to the specific device space you have.

Initially user space is 72 PostScript units to the inch, but unlike device space it is infinitely (subjct to the limitations of the maths library) sub-divisible.

Basically this means that the actual values depend on the resolution of the underlying device.

So, if your underlying device is 96 dpi, then 72 user space PostScript units = 96 device pixels, so each PostScript unit covers 96/72 = 1.3333... device pixels. At 300 dpi 72 PostScript units in default user space would cover 300 device pixels, so 1 PostScript unit would cover 300/72 = 4.1666... device pixels. And so on.

The scale operator (and other operators which alter the CTM) simply alters the mapping between user space and device space. So if we start with a resolution of 144x144 then the CTM would be [2 0 0 2 0 0], each PostScript unit in user space covers 144 device pixels in device space, so 1 unit = 1 inch. If we then apply a 2 2 scale the CTM becomes [4 0 0 4 0 0], so each unit in user space now covers 296 device pixels, or 2 inches at 144 dpi.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. If I use the scale operator, get I a loss of accuracy? I mean when one PostScript point cover 1.3333 device pixels (96 dpi).

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'accuracy', but in most cases no. The point is that user space is infinite and infinitely scalable (up or down). The use of the CTM is so that the page description doesn't have to rely on knowing anything about the underlying device, you can write a PostScript program to describe the output you want, and then take it to a wide variety of devices and it should look the same on all of them. The maths to map from user space to device space is all taken care of (via the CTM) so you just draw what you want in user space, the interpreter deals with rendering it.

Comment: If you want to know the rendering details they are covered in the PostScript Language Reference Manual but basically (and from memory) PostScript uses the 'any part of pixel' approach (when mapping from user space, if any part of a device pixel is covered, the it is turned on) for everything except images. For images it uses the 'centre of pixel' approach, is if the image covers the centre of the pixel then the pixel is drawn.